Force 2 decimal places in xparse
I'd like to force the output of two decimal places. I'm relying on this answer for the code. Values will never be 3 decimal places, but integers will need trailing zeroes. I'm not wedded to xparse if there is a better way...
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \g_total_sum_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddValue}{m}{
  \fp_gadd:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SubValue}{m}{
  \fp_gsub:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ResetSum}{}{
  \fp_zero:N \g_total_sum_fp 
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplaySum}{}{
  \fp_to_decimal:N \g_total_sum_fp
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\AddValue{123.45}
Desired output: 123.45. Actual output: \DisplaySum 

\AddValue{0.05}
Desired output: 123.50. Actual output: \DisplaySum

\AddValue{0.50}
Desired output: 124.00. Actual output: \DisplaySum

\end{document}



You don’t need to load xparse for \NewDocumentCommand today.

You can use the siunitx package and try \num[ minimum-decimal-digits=2 ]{ \fp_to_decimal:N \g_total_sum_fp } in \DisplaySum.

You might use siunitx, but as the job appears to print an amount of money in “<monetary unit> and cents”, we can do it “by hand”.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_new:N \g_total_sum_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddValue}{m}
 {
  \fp_gadd:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\SubValue}{m}
 {
  \fp_gsub:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ResetSum}{}
 {
  \fp_zero:N \g_total_sum_fp 
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\DisplaySum}{}
 {
  \alice_displaysum:e { \fp_to_decimal:N \g_total_sum_fp }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \alice_displaysum:n
 {
  \__alice_displaysum:w #1 .. \q_stop
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \alice_displaysum:n {e}

\cs_new:Npn \__alice_displaysum:w #1.#2.#3 \q_stop
 {
  #1.
  \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
   { 00 }% no decimal part
   { #2\int_compare:nT {1#2<20} {0} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\AddValue{123.45}
Desired output: 123.45. Actual output: \DisplaySum 

\AddValue{0.05}
Desired output: 123.50. Actual output: \DisplaySum

\AddValue{0.50}
Desired output: 124.00. Actual output: \DisplaySum

\end{document}

By design, fp values don't add a decimal point for integers and don't add trailing zeros. But we can do it: we test whether there is a decimal point and, if there's not we print 00. Otherwise the decimal part is available as #2 and we can test whether it's less than 10, in this case adding a trailing zero.

The same with siunitx, but you lose expandability of \DisplaySum.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_new:N \g_total_sum_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddValue}{m}
 {
  \fp_gadd:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\SubValue}{m}
 {
  \fp_gsub:Nn \g_total_sum_fp {#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ResetSum}{}
 {
  \fp_zero:N \g_total_sum_fp 
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplaySum}{}
 {
  \num[minimum-decimal-digits=2]{ \fp_to_decimal:N \g_total_sum_fp }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\AddValue{123.45}
Desired output: 123.45. Actual output: \DisplaySum 

\AddValue{0.05}
Desired output: 123.50. Actual output: \DisplaySum

\AddValue{0.50}
Desired output: 124.00. Actual output: \DisplaySum

\end{document}


That's really great, thanks, how clever

Try this (at the end of your test): \AddValue{0.01} Desired output: 124.01. Actual output: \DisplaySum.

@wipet I see the problem and the fix. Thanks for pointing it out.

@alice19 See the fix I made.

For the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It makes use of Lua's string.format function to achieve the formatting objective.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro (see '\DisplaySum' definition)
% Initialize 'g_total_sum_fp', define four macros
\directlua{ g_total_sum_fp = 0 }
\newcommand\AddValue[1]{%
   \directlua{ g_total_sum_fp = g_total_sum_fp + #1 }}
\newcommand{\SubValue}[1]{%
   \directlua{ g_total_sum_fp = g_total_sum_fp - #1 }}
\newcommand{\ResetSum}{%
   \directlua{ g_total_sum_fp = 0 }}
\newcommand{\DisplaySum}{%
   \luaexec{ tex.sprint ( string.format ( "\%.2f" , g_total_sum_fp )) }}

\begin{document}

\AddValue{123.45}
Desired output: 123.45. Actual output: \DisplaySum 

\AddValue{0.05}
Desired output: 123.50. Actual output: \DisplaySum

\AddValue{0.50}
Desired output: 124.00. Actual output: \DisplaySum

\end{document}

